# unable to do prediction in fastapi and return response

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I have a machine learning API where I am doing predictions. It's working fine before introducing `task_id`. But after adding `task_id` I am getting response as null even though it's working properly but not returning the response

```py
@app.get('/predict')
def predict(task_id,solute: str, solvent: str):
    if task_id ==0:
        results = predictions(solute, solvent)
        response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
        response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
        return {'result': response}
    if task_id == 1:
        return "this is second one"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for returning `null` is that your code never makes it into the `if` statements (which, by the way, should be `if`...`elif`, rather than having two individual `if` statements). This is due to your endpoint receiving `task_id` as a string (i.e., "0", "1", etc), but you check against integer values. Thus, you should declare `task_id` as `int` parameter, as shown below:

```
@app.get('/predict')
def predict(task_id: int, solute: str, solvent: str):
    if task_id == 0:
        results = predictions(solute, solvent)
        response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
        response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
        return {'result': response}
    elif task_id == 1:
        return "this is second one"
    else:
        return "some default response"
```